# Getting a template partial from parent folders

Tags: jinja2

My project is separated into many modules.

Each module has its own `/templates` folder that contains its own relevant template files.

There are common components (header, nav) inside these template files that I wish to extract into 'partials' which are then *included* inside the each module's template files (ie: `{% include 'nav.html' %}`

**The Question**

How can I set up my template environment in such a way that allows for the module's template files to reach into a `shared` folder that contains these partials?

**My Current Environment Setup**

```
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'views')
env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), 
    autoescape=True)

self.render('some_template.html', env=env)   # render function
```

This current configuration only allows me to reach into the `/templates` folder within each module. However, the templates files (inside the `/templates` dir) ***should*** also have access to the partial files that are outside of each module's directory.

Ideally, the app directory would look like this:

```
app/
  shared/
    header.html <-- templates within modules need to access these
    nav.html
  modules/
    module_a/
      handler.py
      templates/
        my_template.html  <-- needs access to partials from 'shared/' 
    module_b/
    module_c/
```